# wordpress theme: on site seo

Tags: seo

I have a site that is not getting the traffic I have been hoping for (not as much traffic as other sites I own) and I am wondering if it might be something with the theme.

The site is *[idolx](http://idolx.net)* (not pornographic but site has pictures of cute girls, just a heads up)

Should I change the theme?
or, Try to optimize it?
or, Is it simply the content?

Any ideas, opinions or advice would be appreciated.

PS: I am not familiar with PHP/coding, etc.

Comment: How does your traffic relates to WordPress? You probably need SEO consultation, not help with WP issue.

Comment: I'm working pretty hard making content that I think there is a demand for, but with few results. Just wondering if the theme might be bad for SEO (has some code that search engines don't like?) I'm not even sure if there is such a thing as a theme that might damage SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Download either [All in One SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/), or [WordPress SEO](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). These should help you create more traffic. You will need to take the time to go post by post, page by page, and add descriptions, titles, keywords, etc. for better SEO rankings.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try one of the plugins.